# How to get an overview of TYPO3's caching status?

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

How can you find out which pages were cached when and how often? I'd like to use the Info Module to list it, if possible, as it seems to have been possible once with the extension cachemgm, at least according to a screenshot from the [old documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cachemgm/stable/Manual/Index.html#screenshots) (this no longer works in the new version).